# NSData to NSString encoding

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, encoding

I have an application that receives messages from server.
Those messages may contain cyrillic characters. But when I transform received data into NSString I obtain only "\u041c\u0430\u043a" symbols instead of cyrrilic ones.

```
   NSData *responceData = ....;

   NSString* responceString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

How may I get correct symbols?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There's a much easier solution.

If your data has literal unicode escape sequences in it (that is, `\u041c\0430\043a` as pure ASCII characters, with no unicode escaping applied), then this is not the UTF-8 encoding of that string. You want `NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding`.

```
NSData *responseData = ....;

NSString* responseString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSNonLossyASCIIStringEncoding];
```

`responseString` will now be exactly what you expect.

Comment: +1 Did not know of a built in solution and would obviously prefer that over an homegrown one :), once my answer is unaccepted I will remove it.

Comment: Yeah, the name doesn't make it super obvious what it is, so lots of people don't know about it.